# Template subclass of non-template base from shared library causing Undefined symbols typeinfo for 'class' link error

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-linking

## Summary

I've built a shared library containing a non-template class from which I've derived a template class within the project that is linked to the library.

When I compile/link the referencing project, I receive the following link error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for BaseClass", referenced from:
      typeinfo for DerivedClass<int> in main.o
```

What does `typeinfo` actually refer to?  I am having trouble finding information about it, in order to dig deeper.

The error almost seems to imply that BaseClass is being expected to have type information of some kind, but I don't understand what is missing.

Also, I know this error often accompanies a `vtable for ...` link error, usually when you forget to provide a definition for a virtual method or define it as pure virtual, but I believe I've ruled that out with #1 in **Things I've Tried** below, since `main.cpp` would not have compile if `foo()`'s definition was not available from the library.

## Source

I've distilled the classes to the following which still reproduce the problem:

**BaseClass.h** (part of shared library I'm linking against)

```
#ifndef BASECLASS_H_
#define BASECLASS_H_

class BaseClass
{
    protected:
        int myField;

    public:
        BaseClass();
        virtual ~BaseClass() {}

        virtual void foo();
};

#endif
```

**BaseClass.cpp** (compiled into the resulting dylib)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BaseClass.h"

__attribute__((visibility("default")))
BaseClass::BaseClass()
    : myField(0)
{

}

__attribute__((visibility("default")))
void BaseClass::foo()
{
    std::cout<<myField<<std::endl;
}
```

**DerivedClass.h** (in separate project that is linked against the library)

```
#ifndef DERIVEDCLASS_H_
#define DERIVEDCLASS_H_

#include <BaseClass.h>

template <typename T>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    protected:
        T data;

    public:
        DerivedClass(T data) : data(data) {}
        virtual ~DerivedClass() {}
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp** (References DerivedClass that's expressing problem)

```
#include "DerivedClass.h"

int main()
{

    DerivedClass<int> derived(0);
    derived.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

### Build commands

**Shared Library**

Compilation:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -MMD -MP -MF"src/BaseClass.d" -MT"src/BaseClass.o" -o "src/BaseClass.o" "../src/BaseClass.cpp"
```

Linking:

```
g++ -Xlinker -install_name -Xlinker "@rpath/libmylibrary.dylib" -dynamiclib -o "libmylibrary.dylib" ./src/BaseClass.o
```

**Referencing Project**

Compilation:

```
g++ -I"/code/myproject/deps/mylibrary/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
```

Linking:

```
g++ -L"/code/myproject/deps/mylibrary/bin" -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker "@loader_path" -o "myproject"  ./src/InternalBaseClass.o ./src/main.o   -lmylibrary
```

### Environment Info

- **OS:** macOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
- **Compiler:** Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) (g++ links to this)
- **Linker:** ld

## Things I've Tried

I've done these things to try to narrow down the cause to specifically being due to the subclass being a template, and the base class coming from a shared library.

1. *Ensuring BaseClass can be referenced on its own.*
    Tested this by changing `main.cpp` to include `BaseClass`, and instantiating it in `main()` and calling `foo()` on it.  Compiled & linked without errors.
2. *Deriving from an internal base class instead of one from a shared library.*
    Tested this by creating a class called `InternalBaseClass` with exact same source, except for the `__attribute__` lines in the definition file, including it in the `DerivedClass` header in place of including `BaseClass`, and specifying it as the parent in the class declaration of `DerivedClass`. Compiled & linked without errors.
3. *Making `DerivedClass` non-template.*
    Tested this by removing template declarations in `DerivedClass` and replacing references to the parameterized type `T` with `int`.  This compiles & links without errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the library compile/link line?  I suspect your problem is how you are building the shared library

Comment: I think you need to put the visibility attributes in the header.  GCC puts the vtable and typeinfo put with the first non in line virtual function.  I suspect that because the way you declared it, they are hidden , and not available to users.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put in the shared library commands - I added them.  You are correct about the visibility in the header for teh class - this fixed.  Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are building your shared library with "-fvisibility=hidden" and mark exported function with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` however in order to export RTTI you need to mark exported class with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`. From [gcc referece](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes):

> Note that the type visibility is applied to vague linkage entities associated with the class (vtable, typeinfo node, etc.). In particular, if a class is thrown as an exception in one shared object and caught in another, the class must have default visibility. Otherwise the two shared objects are unable to use the same typeinfo node and exception handling will break.

Comment: This did it! You were correct, I am compiling the shared library with `-fvisibility=hidden` (updated question text with shared library build commands).  I had not realized the type visibility also is applied to those additional things mentioned in the GCC reference you linked.  Many thanks.